# vim mess up with color and window

Tags: linux, vim

it seems my vim encounters a problem, and it cannot recognize its own filetype, when i edit ~/.vimrc, the syntax isn't highlight while i've set 'syntax on', but when i edit .c file, it has syntax highlight. And another problem is that it seems my VIM is running inside a shell when i edit ~/.vimrc, i can even sroll to my previous commands! And when i edit other file type, it doesn't have the problem. here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you run `:setlocal filetype?`?

Comment: @icktoofay  it returns "filetype="

Comment: What about `:echo exists("did_load_filetypes")`?

Comment: @icktoofay  it returns 1

Comment: And what about `:autocmd BufRead *vimrc*`?

Comment: I think the scrolling can be fixed with `:set mouse=a`, which gives Vim full control of your mouse. See more here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_mouse_for_Vim_in_an_xterm